# SQL Server runs out of internal resources producing query plan

Tags: sql-server

I'm having issues using Visual Studio 2019 to publish a database project to a target server where the database does not yet exist. During the publish process, the following error happens:

> (46075,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 8623, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.
> (46062,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

The error does not appear to be related to specific SQL as the error message would suggest.  If I comment out a script that generates the error, the error shows up in the next script in the sequence. Overall, the publish script produced by VS2019 is approximately 72k lines. The error pops up after approximately 46k lines.

**EDIT:**
Server details:
SQL Server 2019 Developer edition (15.0.2000.5). 4 processors, 16 gb memory

Comment: Are you on the latest update of SQL Server for that version?

Answer (score 0):

This was my system having the problem that Anthony posted about for me. We've now figured out the cause. The root cause was a post deployment script to populate a table with initial values. The script uses a reasonably complex `merge` statement and tried to insert about 18,500 rows of data.

We were thrown off initially because the error output pointed to a different script in the set, not the one causing a problem. Evidently just what was in the error buffer when it burped.